# How to connect iReport to SVN repository

Tags: svn, netbeans, version-control, jasper-reports, ireport

How can I connect iReport to my SVN repository to maintain versioning for my reports?

I'm using iReport **v 5.0.1**

At the moment I'm using RapidSvn to handle versioning of my reports, but I'd like to integrate repository connection in iReport? Is it possible?

**NOTE** I tried to install subversion client plugin but it's an old version. I'm using 1.7 version on my server.

Comment: In my Eclipse w/ SVN workspace when I create a `.jrxml` file I can just right click and check-in that file to SVN. That enables me to keep track of the version of that `jrxml`.

Comment: @onepotato i guess you are using Jasper Studio plugin for Eclipse... not iReport...

Comment: I'm not using any eclipse plugin for my reports. I design my report outside eclipse with iReport. I just saved them inside my project.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue in older version of Jasper while using IReport by exporting repository from server by **buildomatic** and then the result saved as tree of directories into SVN. It is not the most beautiful way, but it works.

Jasper Studio has build in support for SVN and works nice with it, but we could not find option how to use SVN and IReport together in other way as was described.